# FastAPI backend is somehow stuck

Tags: python, fastapi, gunicorn, uvicorn

I have a backend server which is a FastAPI server deployed with Gunicorn and Uvicorn worker class. Sometimes the server stops giving the response right away. I've checked the CPU and RAM usage all looks good. I've checked the docker stats and it also looks good. Its with the overall backend server not with a specific API request. Has anyone faced and solved this issue before? This issue gets resolved when I restart the server then comes back again due to an unknown reason there's no clear pattern here.

- I checked by going inside the docker container of the backend and tried the to get the response from there as well and its not giving me the response right away. Sometime it does sometimes its stuck.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually running enough workers to handle the amount of requests you're seeing? And if you're using async - are you sure you're not calling any blocking functions?

Comment: For gunicorn workers I'm using the following config


`import multiprocessing`

`workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1`
`threads = 2 * multiprocessing.cpu_count()`
`worker_class = "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"`
`bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"`
`keepalive = 2`
`timeout = 30`
`worker_tmp_dir="/dev/shm"`
`accesslog="-"`
`loglevel="debug"`

and for blocking function I'm not sure; The problem is backend behaviour is not the same. This error is not reproducible otherwise I would've known that an API is messing this up.